# Unwanted space when using max-width

Tags: css

I am working on this landing page and I wanted to add to the body a max-width so on bigger size screens would still looks like a normal size. The problem is that it adds a margin or something to the left of some element. At first I had it only on the grid, it didn't looked that bad so I left it . The problem is that now I can see it on the nav bar when I scroll too , and you can see it big time . Is there A way I can fix that ? This is the code pen https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/full/LoOoVm and this is my code on body.

```
body {
  max-width: 1330px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the `max-width: 1330px;` because of this u have issue. You have to give the screen size that should equally set on all screen, so if u set it to `max-width: 100vw` this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `max-width: 1330px;` is the what's causing your issue, as it is only affecting screen sizes larger than the specified size.

If you set it to: `max-width: 100vw;` this clears your white-space issue.

```
body {
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
}
```

Generally speaking setting a `max-width` in `px` to the `<body>` isn't best practice.

Comment: Then how to make it no to be 100% of the display on larger sites ? I don't have a large monitor and I can't optimize the site for large displays . Or how do you deal with larger displays ?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you need a `max-width` on the `<body>`?

Comment: because it looks really bad on large display and I saw a lot of site that are not 100% of the display width so I figure that they are done by adding a max-width .  I am coding for 2 month so far . That's the best idea that i had to make this work

Comment: The `<body>` should really be full width.  It sounds like what you are trying to achieve is to have a wrapper `<div>` and set a `max-width` and `margin: auto;` on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
body, html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

That's standard practice and should be enough. Setting the max width isn't practical for some displays. You should always use percentages or viewport widths.

Comment: it doesn't work . On large screens this page look really wired also. The header is 100% all the time but the rest of the content is 1330px . If I would use % or vw then it will be a % of the screen on all display sizes